# Switch classes on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two links that can trigger a collapsed menu (1) linked text, and (2) an icon.

```
<div class="brand"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content">Browse by Collection</a></div> 

<i class="toggle-btn ion-android-add" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>

<ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse">...</ul>
```

I'd like to make it so that when the collapsed menu is opened via any of the two methods, the plus (`.ion-android-add`) changes to a minus (`.ion-android-remove`), and then turns back into a plus when menu is collapsed.

I've tried various jquery snippets found in other answers, such as toggling classes, or adding/removing class but nothing seemed to do the trick. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I ended up getting it to work with this code:

```
$('.toggle-btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('ion-android-add ion-android-remove');
});
```

However, that only works for the button. How can I make it so that when I click the brand div, it will affect the icon as well?

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried as a jumping off point :)

Comment: Try using inner html to edit the class attribute with javascript

Comment: @Qwerty how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy doing it with jQuery. There are more ways, but this one came to my mind first:

```
$('.ion-android-add').click(function(){
 $(this).removeClass('ion-android-add').addClass('ion-android-remove');
});

$('.ion-android-remove').click(function(){
 $(this).removeClass('ion-android-remove').addClass('ion-android-add');
});
```

Comment: That works well but then it won't toggle back once I want to expand it again. It stays with a minus.